# Can't set desired view to focus when multiple views in area of focus change

Tags: focus, tvos, apple-tv

I'm having a hard time finding a solution to this so I thought I might as well ask to see if anyone has a better solution to this than I have. So to frame the question say I have a UI layout like so. [image]

Where one focusable view is much larger than the other. And contains multiple valid focusable views underneath it when the user changes focus downward. Something like this.

[image]

My question is what is a good way to enforce that the button to the far left is focused as apposed to the other buttons.

So far the only solution I can think of is to override canBecomeFocused in a custom button subclass, and return the value of a settable variable.

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    var isFocusable = true 
    canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return isFocusable
    }
}
```

Then change the value of isFocusable based on where I want the focus to go next. It works but I'm not super happy with it. Just wondering if maybe someone else can think of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out UIKitCatalogtvOSCreatingandCustomizingUIKitControls example from Apple at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html

Check out FocusGuide behaviour or shouldFocusAtItem and canFocusAtItem to get your preferredFocus behaviour.